# Reference to pointer from function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have code (bottom) and how can I save reference to pointer (to object TRequest), because I must save same object (with same address) send to other function.

```
void producent(const TRequest *(* dispatcher)( void )) {
    // ...
    const TRequest *& tmpRequest2 = *(dispatcher()); // that is bad
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::function` along with `std::bind`?

Answer (score 0):

Your tmpRequest2 should be of type, const TRequest*. (Without the ampersand and do not dereference the returned value) Because you do not want to create a reference to the pointer just returned from the function, which is a temporary. It would the be a reference to an non existing value, because the actual value is never stored. The approach to simply store and use a reference a reference to the value of at which the pointer points in this case would be something like this:

```
     const TRequest *tmpRequest2Ptr = (dispatcher());
     if (tmpRequest2Ptr != nullptr)
     {
         const TRequest & tmpRequest2 = *tmpRequest2Ptr;
         // do something with tmpRequest2
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value (here a const TRequest*) is a temporary. You should not save reference to a temporary.

Three options:

- Don't store a reference, store instead the pointer directly

> const TRequest * tmpRequest2 = *(dispatcher());

- Change the return type of dispatcher and return a reference to pointer. This means the actual pointer whose a reference is returned has to be stored in a permanent location.

> void producent(const TRequest * &(* dispatcher)( void )) {

- Store the result in a pointer (and not a ref to pointer) and create a reference on it (but the stored pointer must be kept valid in that case). I do not think this will solve your problem but that's just for understanding

  ```
  //tmpRequest2 must remain in scope during the use of tmpRequest3
  const TRequest * tmpRequest2 = *(dispatcher());
  const TRequest *& tmpRequest3 = tmpRequest2;
  ```

Why can't you simply send the pointer to the other function? Does the other function needs to modify the pointer or simply to access the TObject?